# Are cores in a CPU package always identical?

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture, core, processor-socket

By identical, I mean having the same signature - family, model, stepping and brand string of the CPU (which essentially identifies a CPU model uniquely)

If I'm not wrong, a CPU package goes into a CPU socket on a motherboard.

**edit:** oops, I forgot to add that I was looking for info related to Intel server CPUs (Xeon and similar). Nothing specific, just wanted to know whether CPU packages in servers have always had exactly the same CPUs. Thanks!

Comment: Please reduce the scope of your question.  CPU manufactures use both heterogeneous  and homogeneous multi-core designs.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Ramhound, I need to make a list of CPUs in a server host. Just wondering whether I can assume that all CPUs are the same in a CPU package, less work for me.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by a CPU package.  You can assume a Xeon processor of a particular model will be identical to another Xeon processor of the same model.  Any differences that might exist wouldn't even be detectable

Answer (score 3):

No.

Example: Some of the SoC phones which have 4 fast and one slow (and more power efficient) core. Example: [Tegra 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tegra).

Comment: On a side note OEMs advertise such phones ( with 4 fast and 4 slow cores) as Octa Core yet slow and fast cores don't work at same time meaning while they do have 8 cores in theory,  they work as Quad Core in real life

Comment: Note: the question is tagged *Intel*, so I am assuming the OP is concerned with Intel x86. So far Intel has not adopted heterogeneous multicore (though due to process variation it might be possible to use turboboost more often on one core than another; the same would apply to user overclocking).

Comment: I saw the tag Intel, but nothing about Intel (x86, Itanium,, ...) was mentioned in the question.  Closest Intel answer I have is the i7 9x0 series which turbo's on at most one core.

Comment: just edited the question